# Acer aspire X; AXC-603G-UW15

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, acer-aspire

I believe i was hacked, and somehow my C drive was LOCKED, running win8.1, and when i rebooted my computer, windows couldn't be found, the comp. did not come with a recovery disk, and i have tried all the things said to recover or fix, nothing works.  So i brought a new hard drive, but can't install anything cause of factory safeguards, which can only be accessed from the original hard drive, which is dead til i get an OS loaded to the new hard drive, how can i get passed the factory safeguard, nothing in CMOS changes the setup access.

Answer (score 0):

The CMOS settings of many computers can be accessed by one of the programs you can run before choosing which operating system to boot (if you have more than one installed, but not on the same disk partition).  Explore what's available.  For Windows, the D drive usually contains a separate operating system plus the files needed to install Windows on the C drive plus a number of files useful for fixing problems that keep the C drive from booting.  It often also contains a program for creating a recovery disk.

This partition could allow you to install the original operating system on your new drive, but you'll need to get past the rather different way it names the various drives and partitions.

I don't have any Acer computer available to check if this should work for you, though.

I've seen some computers where the back or the bottom of the computer has a label that includes the computer's serial number and MAY contain some other information needed to get past the factory safeguards.